# FormHttpMessageConverter filename from byte array

Tags: java, spring, post, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload file with POST request. POST must be of the enclosure-type multipart/form-data. I insert file as byte array:

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> requestParameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();

byte[] image=getImage();

// ... adding parameters in requestParameters       
// TODO filename
requestParameters .add("file", image);
```

Then I make post request with 
org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter:

```
FormHttpMessageConverter multipartFormConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
        multipartFormTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        multipartFormTemplate.setMessageConverters(Collections.<HttpMessageConverter<?>> singletonList(multipartFormConverter));

        ResponseEntity<String> uploadAnswer=multipartFormTemplate.postForEntity(freePlanResponse.getUrl(), requestParameters, String.class);
```

**The problem is - I cant found, how to change filename**. The result is always default filename (*${filename}*) for file hosting, I'm using:
[image hosting](https://github.com/cloudapp/api/blob/master/upload-file.md). It uses:
amazon s3. Here is [post example >>](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTExamples.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

Inherit FormHttpMessageConverter and override getFileName method:

```
public class FormHttpMessageConverterImageName extends FormHttpMessageConverter {

    private String filename;

    public void setFilename(String filename){
        this.filename=filename;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getFilename(Object part) {
        return filename;
    }
}
```

but maybe there is some more beautifull solution.